# Yii2 - validate date base on 3 input fields and show error message if the date is not valid

Tags: yii, yii2

How can I validate date and show error message, if the date is made from 3 input fields? This are the fields:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 reg2-div">
<div class="col-xs-3 reg2-db-div">
<?php echo $form->field($model_data_step_2, 'recipient_birth_month')->textInput() ?>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-1 reg2-db-div">
<span style="font-size: 50px;">/</span>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-3 reg2-db-div">
<?php echo $form->field($model_data_step_2, 'recipient_birth_day')->textInput() ?>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-1 reg2-db-div">
<span style="font-size: 50px;">/</span>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4 reg2-db-div">
<?php echo $form->field($model_data_step_2, 'recipient_birth_year')->textInput() ?>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

write a custom rule in the model

i am writing a dummy model

```
class SignupForm extends Model
{
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ['recipient_birth_month', 'checkMonth'],
            ['recipient_birth_day', 'checkDay'],
            ['recipient_birth_year', 'checkYear'],

            // other rules
        ];
    }

    public function checkMonth($attribute, $params)
    {
        //  the error is triggered if >12
        if($this->recipient_birth_month > 12 )
            $this->addError($attribute, Yii::t('user', 'You entered an invalid month.'));
    }
    public function checkMonth($attribute, $params)
    {
        //  the error is triggered
        if($this->recipient_birth_day> 31 )
            $this->addError($attribute, Yii::t('user', 'You entered an invalid Day.'));
    }
    public function checkMonth($attribute, $params)
    {
        //  the error is triggered
        if($this->recipient_birth_year > 2016 )
            $this->addError($attribute, Yii::t('user', 'You entered an invalid Year.'));
    }
}
```

hope this helps
if you just want a single error message instead of having 3 create a custom validation like this

```
class SignupForm extends Model
    {
        public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ['recipient_birth_year', 'allinonedatecheck'],
            // other rules
        ];
    }

    public function allinonedatecheck($attribute, $params)
    {
        //  the error is triggered if >12
        if($this->recipient_birth_month > 12 )
            $this->addError($attribute, Yii::t('user', 'You entered an invalid month.'));

        //  the error is triggered
        if($this->recipient_birth_day > 31 )
            $this->addError($attribute, Yii::t('user', 'You entered an invalid Day.'));

        //  the error is triggered
        if($this->recipient_birth_year > 2016 )
            $this->addError($attribute, Yii::t('user', 'You entered an invalid Year.'));
    }
}
```

Now the error message will be shown only @ the recipient_birth_year even if the day is wrong

> if you want to check if the date is correct you can use the yii2
>   validator

```
class SignupForm extends Model
    {
        public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ['recipient_birth_year', 'datecheck'],
            // other rules
        ];
    }

    public function datecheck($attribute, $params)
    {

        $d =new \yii\validators\DateValidator ();
        $d->format = 'MM/dd/yyyy'; // date in ICU format
        if(!$d->validate($this->recipient_birth_month ."/".$this->recipient_birth_day."/".$this->recipient_birth_year))
        {
             $this->addError($attribute, Yii::t('user', 'You entered an invalid Date.'));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: User can enter date like 31-02-2015 (31st February doesn’t exist). I also need to validate date.

Comment: instead of checking each attribute seperately, just validate the date with
    `bool checkdate ( int $month , int $day , int $year )`
and add an error if it returns false

Comment: i have written some more code where i have appended the values to make a date string and that string is validated using yii2 date validator